# Anybody knows how to "fix" this blurry font that's only on snap-store?

Tags: gnome, fonts, snap, wayland, 21.10

The issue I'm facing is pretty much described with the title and the screenshot below.

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10, Gnome 40, Wayland display manager on a machine powered by ryzen 5 4500u with radeon graphics (incase any of that is needed to diagonise the issue).

Enlarge the image and see the difference in font readability betweeen the dash/status bar vs snap-store

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be [bug #1871779](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store-desktop/+bug/1871779).

I saw the same as you when using snap-store from the latest/stable channel. Then I switched to latest/beta:

```
snap remove snap-store
snap install snap-store --channel=latest/beta
```

and it made a huge difference with respect to font rendering.

Comment: thanks it worked